# How can I learn why kswapd has very low page reclaim efficiency?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory, postgresql, cgroups

### Problem/context

I have a (managed) Postgres 10.16 instance running on Fedora 32 in a systemd-nspawn container. Periodically, I see a big spike in "system" CPU usage in our metrics, correlated with a sudden drop in Postgres query throughput and disk activity, lasting anywhere from 30 seconds to a few minutes. Our metrics collector also collects at irregular intervals instead of every 10s. The problem happens about once a day.*

### The clue

I ran some diagnostics the last time this happened and noticed that during most of the low-performance period:

- kswapd was using 100% of a core
- By looking at periodic dumps of `/proc/vmstat`, I noticed the ratio of the change in `pgsteal_kswapd` to the change in `pgscan_kswapd` was 0.014.

That is, it seems that kswapd was trying to reclaim pages from the page cache, but had to look at ~70 pages for each page it reclaimed. [This man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sar) suggests that a ratio lower than 0.3 is concerning. During a 50-second period in one of the incidents, kswapd scanned a total of 2.3m pages and reclaimed only 32,000 of them.

I suspect this pathological page cache reclaim behavior is related to the performance issues that correlated with it. I also suspect it could be related to the fact that postgres is running in a container here, a la [this similar but not identical issue](https://engineering.fb.com/2020/08/31/developer-tools/zookeeper-twine/) (unfortunately, not a decision we can change as that's up to the hosting provider). But I'm not sure concretely what could be causing the behavior or how to root-cause or fix it.

### The question

I have two related questions:

- What type of memory/disk access patterns could cause this low reclaim efficiency?
- What information can I collect next time this happens, or how can I debug, to narrow down the possibility space?

### Appendix: hypotheses I've considered and rejected

[This book](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand013.html) gives two reasons for low page reclaim efficiency:

> There are only two cases where the algorithm is likely to behave really badly. The first is if the candidates for reclamation are principally anonymous pages. In this case, Linux will keep examining a large number of pages before linearly scanning process page tables searching for pages to reclaim but this situation is fortunately rare.

We dumped `/proc/meminfo` at the same time, this showed that a high percentage of inactive pages are "file", not "anon" (as is typical for Postgres, which recommends allocating much of the machine's memory to the page cache). So I don't think this can apply to us.

> The second situation is where there is a single process with many file backed resident pages in the inactive_list that are being written to frequently. Processes and kswapd may go into a loop of constantly “laundering” these pages and placing them at the top of the inactive_list without freeing anything. In this case, few pages are moved from the active_list to inactive_list as the ratio between the two lists sizes remains not change significantly.

Per the vmstat dumps, `nr_dirtied` only increased by about 33k during the incident, while `pgscan_kswapd` increased by 2.3m. So kswapd was scanning pages much faster than they were being written and this can't be the issue either.

*It's not currently happening because I upgrade to a massively overprovisioned instance with 50% more cores and 2x as much RAM.